# Unrecognized element <system.transactions> in web.config ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, web-config

I am attempting to set a default transaction timeout setting in my web.config of my ASP.NET MVC 4 application.  I place the following between the end tag of  and the start of

```
<system.transactions>
    <defaultSettings timeout="00:05:00" />
 </system.transactions>
```

This works fine in my local development environment and on one of our development servers, but on a test server I receive a yellow screen of death with a parse error indicating that the element  is not recognized.

What should I be looking for in the machine.config or applicationhost.config that would be preventing the setting from being recognized?

Comment: You've placed `<system.transactions>` as a first level child of `<configuration>`, right?

Comment: I agree, its usually "placement".

Comment: Yes, it is a direct child of "configuration".

Answer (score 0):

This paramter must be defined in machine.config of your IIS.

> Path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\[your Framework version]\Config\

And there you can to define where you will override this later. 
By default, you cannot override this parametr in web.config of your application and in this code.

After that you should read about transaction escalation
[Transaction Management Escalation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/transactions/transaction-management-escalation)

What kind of transaction will be it is depend from used resources type. (on local machine by shared memory, or distributed tran with DB on another machine).

I saw different behaivors. When I used two servers (SQLSERVER and IIS) then System.Transactions was escaleted  to distribute transaction and Timeout parameter defined in machine.config works fine. But when SQLSERVER and IIS was on the same machine - timeout was ingored, and I can't understand why(( In this case system transaction was not escalated to distributed transaction (I saw it in sys.dm_tran_active_transactions), and I expected that Timeout will be 10 minutes (default). But this transaction work several hours.

I am trying to figure it out.